# Get absolute url from relative url in firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom

In my FF extension, I want to get the absolute URL of all the links in a page. I know this can be done by JS. But I want to know whether this can be done by any FF service.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, getting an absolute URL of a link is trivial:

```
console.log(doc.links[0].href);
```

The `href` property of a link (**not** the `href` attribute) is always resolved automatically so that you get an absolute URL with no effort whatsoever.

I suspect that what you really want is to resolve a relative URL that you got from somewhere. You use [nsIIOService](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIIOService) for this:

```
var ioService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                          .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var baseURI = ioService.newURI("http://example.com/index.html", null, null);
var absURI = ioService.newURI("/test.gif", null, baseURI);
console.log(absURI.spec);
```

This example gives you `http://example.com/test.gif` as result, the relative URL `/test.gif` has been resolved relative to the page address `http://example.com/index.html`.